# Comparing two lists and counting boolean values in Netlogo

Tags: simulation, netlogo

I have two seperate lists, *reality* and *individuals*, and they have values between *-1,1* and *-1,0,1*, respectively; *n= 30*.

I need to compare these two lists and count the *TRUE*s to set it as a property for the individuals at setup. In other words, I need to check whether or not the first objects in both of the lists are identical (-1 or 1), and if they have the same value, then prompt TRUE, otherwise FALSE, and so on and so forth. Then, count the number of TRUEs to set it as a turtle's "accuracy."

Can anyone help me with implementing this?

Thank you for your help.

```
  create-realities 1 [
    set shape "square"
    set dimensions []
    repeat m [set dimensions fput one-of [-1 1] dimensions]
  ]

  create-individuals n [
    set knowledge []
    repeat m [set knowledge fput one-of [-1 0 1] knowledge] ;set knowledge to length m with random value (-1,0,1)
    set accuracy "HERE"
```

Comment: Hi, from your question it is not clear what your desired output would be. Can you explain it?

Comment: Hi Matteo, thank you for your message. I need to check whether or not the first objects in both of the lists are identical (-1 or 1), and if they have the same value, then prompt TRUE, otherwise FALSE, and so on and so forth. Then, count the number of TRUEs to set it as a turtle's "accuracy."

Comment: Got it, thanks. Will be posting an answer as soon as I have more time

Answer (score 1):

For your specific question, I suggest making use of `map` and `filter`. Both of these require the usage of anonymous procedures. If you are interested in how exactly the syntax for that works I'm going to refer you to the [Netlogo Programming guide](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#anonymous-procedures).

[`map`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#map) allows you to apply a reporter to all individual items of a list, collect these results, and put them in a new list. It can also be used with multiple lists at the same time, allowing you to compare the first items of two lists, the second items of both lists etc. (The syntax I'm using here is very similar ot the one used in the last example in the Netlogo dictionary).
`let comparison (map [ [value-1 value-2] -> value-1 = value-2] list-1 list-2)`.
In this specific case, the function creates a list containing TRUE and FALSE booleans.

Next, [filter](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#filter) allows you to look at this newly create true/false list and filter out all the true values. (For the syntax I will once again refer to the Netlogo dictionary and programming guide)
`let all-trues filter [boolean -> boolean = true] comparison`

Once you have this filtered list, all you need to do now is calculate the `length` of it and you have your accuracy.

```
to test
  
  let list-1 [] 
  repeat 30 [set list-1 lput one-of [-1 1 ] list-1]
  print list-1
  
  let list-2 [] 
  repeat 30 [set list-2 lput one-of [-1 0 1 ] list-2]  
  print list-2
  
  let comparison (map [ [value-1 value-2] -> value-1 = value-2] list-1 list-2)
  print comparison
  
  let all-trues filter [boolean -> boolean] comparison
  print all-trues
  
  let count-of-trues length all-trues
  print count-of-trues
  
end
```